# Issue with Bluetooth Device pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing one simple Bluetooth application where I want to send a text message. Facing issues when trying to pair the devices, it throws exception “java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed”. For more details I am posting code herewith.
Ported application on LG phone Android version 2.3.3

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
BluetoothDevice btDevice = BluetoothActivity.btDevices.get(position).getBtDevice();

clientSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

//Method m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class } );                   
//clientSocket =(BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(btDevice, MY_UUID);

//Method m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class }); 
//clientSocket =(BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(btDevice, 1);

if(clientSocket!=null)
{

    if(BluetoothActivity.btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        BluetoothActivity.btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

}
//facing issue during paring                        
clientSocket.connect();

tmpOut = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
tmpOut.write("HelloWorld.txt".getBytes());
if(tmpOut!=null){
    tmpOut.close();
}   
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated,

Comment: So is `clientSocket.connect()` the line causing the exception?  And is btDevice properly being set to the device you want?  I've found that I need to manually connect to the other BT device through the phone settings before getting a socket set up.

Comment: @Pravin008 You are connecting only between Android powered devices or with PC and other devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this UUID:

```
fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66
```

for some reason, this was the only UUID I could ever get to work... I have no idea why.

Comment: I'm using "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" in my app just fine.  As long as they are the same for both client/server it should be OK.

Comment: @Atlos, not true... at least in my experience. I tested this problem *extensively* and it never worked. Was testing with a Nexus One (2.3.7) and a Motorola XOOM (3.2). When I used the the UUID above all worked fine, but when I changed it to a randomly generated UUID (i.e. using `java.util.UUID`) and changed *nothing* else, I got the same "service discovery error" as the OP described. Do you have any idea why this might occur?

Comment: Interesting.  I'm poking around the `bthdef.h` file I used to create my server and noticed that my value is commented as `// Bluetooth base UUID for service discovery` and then later as `DEFINE_GUID(SerialPortServiceClass_UUID`.  This is the most common UUID I've found to be used in examples on the internet and it wouldn't make sense that it doesn't work for you.  Maybe my first comment was too general then.